# Is it possible to store in a database the output of geodjango's geoqueryset.distance?

Tags: django, geodjango

Is it possible to store the output of geodjango's queryset in a spatially enabled database?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance-lookups 
the one in this example display's all the distances. is it possible to actually store it in the database or even use the value of the geoqueryset.distance for further computations?

Comment: Yes, you can do both with geodjango.

Comment: oh okay. but i'm quite unsure how. since the geometry has to be saved first? am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both can be done in geodjango.

Below is an example of how you could perform a distance calculation without storing any geometry:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
pnt = Point(0,0)
pnt.distance(Point(0,1))
```

Which would return 1.0.  The Django queryset API is specifically built to interact with data so you need some persistant data before querysets become useful.  Once you have data, especially geospatial data, Django querysets become really cool.

Let's look at the example from the docs:

```
Zipcode.objects.filter(poly__distance_gt=(geom, D(m=5)))
```

This will return all of the Zip Codes whose geometry is within 5 meters of geom.  GeoDjango will also append a distance field to each item in your queryset with the distance object that was computed. Since django is just python, you can use the distance values for whatever crazy computations you want:

```
zips = Zipcode.objects.filter(poly__distance_gt=(geom, D(m=5)))
for zip_code in zips:
    print zip_code.name, zip_code.distance.m
```